# PHP: query function erron executing update query string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a query. This query works with phpMyAdmin, but I have an error when this query is execute by PHP. What could be the reason?

My PHP code is:

```
var_dump($sql);
query($sql);
```

when I debug:

this is the query string:

```
 UPDATE searchcolumnsets SET name = "Project X",jsonfields = "[{\"name\":\"cm:contentPropertyName\",\"title\":\"Thumbnailed Content Property Name\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:defaultHomeFolderPath\",\"title\":\"Percorso cartella homepage\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"trx:enabled\",\"title\":\"Abilitato\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:identifier\",\"title\":\"Identificativo\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:expiryDate\",\"title\":\"Data di scadenza\",\"description\":\"Data di scadenza\",\"datatype\":\"d:date\"},{\"name\":\"cm:hits\",\"title\":\"Conteggio\",\"description\":\"Conteggio\",\"datatype\":\"d:int\"}]" WHERE id = 50
```

this is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name":"cm:contentPropertyName","title":"Thumbnailed Content Property Name","desc' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use single qoute instead.
try this

```
UPDATE searchcolumnsets SET name = 'Project X',jsonfields = '[{\"name\":\"cm:contentPropertyName\",\"title\":\"Thumbnailed Content Property Name\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:defaultHomeFolderPath\",\"title\":\"Percorso cartella homepage\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"trx:enabled\",\"title\":\"Abilitato\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:identifier\",\"title\":\"Identificativo\",\"description\":\"\",\"datatype\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"cm:expiryDate\",\"title\":\"Data di scadenza\",\"description\":\"Data di scadenza\",\"datatype\":\"d:date\"},{\"name\":\"cm:hits\",\"title\":\"Conteggio\",\"description\":\"Conteggio\",\"datatype\":\"d:int\"}]' WHERE id = 50
```